# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing Utility class

Tags: java

Im trying to implement a simple rectangle, but i am getting incompatible class change error..
Expecting non-static method Utility.printLine()
The error is on line,

```
    util.printLine();
```

Any help??

the complete code is as follow..

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class Rectangle
{

    private double height;
    private double width;

    public double getHeight()       
    {
        return height;
    }
    public double getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public void setHeight(double x) 
    {
        if(x<=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Height");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            height = x;
        }
    }

    public void setWidth(double x)
    {
        if(x<=0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Width");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            width = x;
        }
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        double a;
        a = height*width;
        return a;
    }
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        double p;
        p = 2*(height+width);
        return p;
    }
}


class Utility
{
    public  void printLine()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=40;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("=");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public  void printLine(char ch)         
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=40;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public  void printLine(char ch, int x)          
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

class RectTest7
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double area, peri, x;

        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Utility util = new Utility();

        System.out.print("Enter height : ");
        x = input.nextDouble();

        r.setHeight(x);

        System.out.print("Enter width : ");
        x = input.nextDouble();

        r.setWidth(x);

        area = r.getArea();
        peri = r.getPerimeter();

        util.printLine();
        System.out.println("Height : "+r.getHeight());
        util.printLine();
        System.out.println("Width : "+r.getWidth());
        util.printLine();
        System.out.println("Area : "+area);
        util.printLine();
        System.out.println("Perimeter : "+peri);
        util.printLine();

        r = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the entire message, quoted exactly??

Comment: And have you recompiled everything since you last modified Utility.java?

Comment: Exception in thread “main” java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expecting non-static method Utility.printLine()
at RectTest7.main(RectTest7.java:113)

Comment: And have you recompiled everything?

Comment: yes sir i have compiled the RectTeast7

Comment: I tried the code exactly as it is written and it compiled and ran just fine.

Comment: So everything is in one .java file?  Question: Do you, by any chance, have a copy of Utility.class elsewhere, in a directory that's in your classpath?

Comment: Yes I have one extra utility.class file in folder

Comment: Remove it.  The JVM is finding the wrong version.

Comment: Yeah .....its working now...